# Complex Arel conditions with AND and OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I have a question about composing several conditions with `AND` and `OR` in one with regards to operations priority.

So, I need to generate following SQL string to pass in to the `where` method:

```
where("NOT ((assignments.to IS NOT NULL AND assignments.to < :start_date) OR assignments.from > :end_date)", start_date: date.at_beginning_of_week, end_date: date.at_end_of_week)
```

I rewrote it with Arel:

```
table = Assignment.arel_table
where(
  table[:from].gt(date.at_end_of_week).
  or(
    table[:to].not_eq(nil).and(table[:to].lt(date.at_end_of_week))
  ).not
)
```

But Arel doesn't put brackets around condition with `AND` and as result this condition selects wrong data. How I can put brackets in this condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `table.grouping` method to wrap the expression in a parenthesis, so the whole  thing can be like this

```
table = Assignment.arel_table
where(
  table[:from].gt(date.at_end_of_week).
  or(
    table.grouping(table[:to].not_eq(nil).and(table[:to].lt(date.at_end_of_week)))
  ).not
)
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try:

```
table[:from].lt(end_date).and(
  table[:to].eq(nil).or(table[:to].gt(start_date))
)
```

maybe I miss something, but in any case you should avoid using `NOT` in sql or `unless` in ruby because it's not good practice

Comment: May be it's possible to avoid using `not` but not in my case. But anyway my question was not about `not` but about grouping.